# Android Studio: When I start a project I forked but get a error "No variants found for 'app'."

Tags: android, android-studio

Literally, I get a error in Android Studio.
App directory exists there! But Whenever I build this, I can't pass the error.
I don't know what should I do.

It's a first time to open a project made by others.
I wanna learn proper way to open Project made by others in this time.
Please anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edM8Y.png)

Comment: Please insert `app/build.gradle` of this app to question.

Comment: @DominikMurzynowski I changed an image. thanks!

Comment: Start by accepting licenses for SDK, then restart build by clicking on hammer icon. I've downloaded the project and got no issues with importing it to Android Studio (by opening the project directory) and building library and app.